# integrated tomcat apache script alias error 404

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat, cgi

I am trying to get a web interface running that is connected to a cgi backend. In order to serve the jsp and cgi, I integrated tomcat and apache and it works. However, when editing apache's httpd.conf with ScriptAlias to make it find CGI-Executables, it won't pick up the given path and whenever I try to access the CGI I get a 404 Error. The AJP connector is working and connecting, it redirects to Port 8009, and all other configurations for CGI are set in the httpd.conf file. Why won't Apache find and execute the CGI script?

`[proxy:debug] [pid 2741] proxy_util.c(2417): [client ::1:50909] AH00947: connected /cgi-bin/testing.cgi to localhost:8009, referer: http://localhost/testing.jsp` This is a line in httpd error.log when the JSP form action calls the CGI File. I am using Mac OSX version 10.12 (Sierra) and Apache version 2.4.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed httpd.conf to only proxy JSP's to tomcat.